# How to download multiple images of table view cell in background?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i want to create an application in one row of tableView there will be 4 images of button which will be loaded from server in background because if i directly load them than the table view will hang some. for this i have used this code for creating button in cell and performing to download images in background.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *hlCellID = @"hlCellID";

        UITableViewCell *hlcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];
        if(hlcell == nil) {
            hlcell =  [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:hlCellID] autorelease];
            hlcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        int section = indexPath.section;
        NSMutableArray *sectionItems = [sections objectAtIndex:section];

        int n = [sectionItems count];

        int i = 0, j = 0, tag = 1;
        int x = 10;
        int y = 30;

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        for (i = 1; i<= n ; i++) //[arr count]
        {
            for(j=1; j<=4;j++)
            {

                if (i>=n) break;
                Item *item = [sectionItems objectAtIndex:i];

                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x = x, y = y, 68, 65); 
                UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
                [button setFrame:rect];
                UIImage *buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:item.image];
                [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
                // set the image to be loaded (using the same one here but could/would be different)
                NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://londonwebdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/featured_home.png"];      

                // Create an array with the URL and imageView tag to 
                // reference the correct imageView in background thread.
                NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imgURL, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tag], nil  ];

                // Start a background thread by calling method to load the image
                [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:arr];
    //          button.tag = [tagValue intValue];
                button.tag = tag;
                //NSLog(@"....tag....%d", button.tag);

                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];
                [button release];

                tag++;

                x = x + 77; 

            }
            x = 10;
            y = y + 74;
        }
        [pool release];
        return hlcell;
    }
```

the above code work perfectly but when i download the images and trying to assign at the some particular button than i can't find the button tags althoug i can find the button tags while `touchupinside` action.

```
- (void) loadImageInBackground:(NSArray *)urlAndTagReference  {

    NSLog(@"Received URL for tagID: %@", urlAndTagReference);

    // Create a pool
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Retrieve the remote image. Retrieve the imgURL from the passed in array
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]];
    UIImage *img    = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

    // Create an array with the URL and imageView tag to 
    // reference the correct imageView in background thread.
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img, [urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1], nil  ];

    // Image retrieved, call main thread method to update image, passing it the downloaded UIImage
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignImageToImageView:) withObject:arr waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool release];

}

    - (void) assignImageToImageView:(NSArray *)imgAndTagReference
    {

        // Create a pool
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        int i;
        UIButton *checkView;

    //  [imagesForCategories addObject:[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1]];
    //    UITableViewCell *cell = [celebCategoryTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1]];
    //    UIImageView *profilePic = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    //    profilePic.image = [imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0];


    //  checkView.tag = [[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        // loop
        for (UIButton *checkView in [self.tblImage subviews] ) 
        { i++;
            NSLog(@"Checking tag: %d against passed in tag %d",checkView.tag, [[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1] intValue]);
            if ([checkView tag] == [[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1] intValue]) {

                if (i==35) break;
                // Found imageView from tag, update with img
    //          [checkView setImage:[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]];
                [checkView setImage:[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                //set contentMode to scale aspect to fit
                checkView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

                //change width of frame
                CGRect frame = checkView.frame;
                frame.size.width = 80;
                checkView.frame = frame;

            }
        }   

        // release the pool
        [pool release];

        // Remove the activity indicator created in ViewDidLoad()
        [self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

the all code works perfect but i can't find the table cell subview here `for (UIButton *checkView in [self.tblImage subviews]` so how to find the subviews of table cell subviews.?

[i want to create something like this pls see image.!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4ZJG.png) after that new city will come and just section change the data will show new images in row and cell section.

Comment: Apple sample link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394

Comment: sir i have seen this example but i think this do not satisfy my question.

Comment: Please call me by name. If you have n number of images into UITableview then you have to go for lazy loading concept. That means load all the lightweight components such UILabels,UIButton first. After some delay start loading images in the background thread(preferably after 0.3 sec). By this you can achieve good solid performance.

Comment: can you tell me how can i find the subviews of table cell? as here you can see `UIButton *checkView in [self.tblImage subviews]` i have used this code but it is not giving me the counts of subviews in table view row cells items.

Comment: Your self.tblImage doesn't contain any view under his belt. You want to check table cell's subviews. So you need to some how pass the UITableviewCell object and extract the subview from it.

Comment: I can see you are passing arr object with loadImageInBackground method in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method. Add indexpath object to it. So that you can retrieve UITableviewCell in assignImageToImageView  method.

Comment: @NaveenThunga thanks i solved my problem by passing row index now i am implementing for multiple rows indexpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Web Image
This library provides a category for UIImageVIew with support for remote images coming from the web.

It provides:

An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework
An asynchronous image downloader
An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling
A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times
A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
Performances!

just use it

```
[youImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRetryFailed];
```

Comment: please see updates question and guide me what should i do? this all code works perfectly in scroll view but i want to create in table view. because i want to make search functionality also.